# Referencing resources in a global way either from a virtual directory or the web root?

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, root, virtual-directory

Let's say I have an MVC/WebAPI/AngularJS site that I'm running locally, e.g. ;

localhost/Test/

which I then want to move to

www.test.com

While local, I have a lot of references to various directories (jsfiles, etc) of the following format (in either JS or HTML files)

```
app.directive('rpdbSpinner', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        **templateUrl: '/Test/templates/directives/spinner.html',**
        scope: {
            isLoading:'='
        }
    }
})
```

when updating/web publishing, I'd have to change everything to:

```
app.directive('rpdbSpinner', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        **templateUrl: '/templates/directives/spinner.html',**
        scope: {
            isLoading:'='
        }
    }
})
```

I can do this manually (which is what I've been doing),but the larger the project grows, the harder it becomes. I could, of course, only change it once and then excluded the files during publishing phase (web.config/rest), but it still feels like I am going about it the wrong way. Using "~/" wouldn't work on plain HTML/JS files as far as I'm aware, and this I can't really use it...

Any suggestions to map to paths globally regardless of whether in a Virtual Directory or the root of a project?

Thanks :)

Comment: Set the baseUrl on the root html/.Net page. Create a branch for publishing that has the correct baseUrl for the server environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply care about getting the root/base url of the site so you can append that to get the other url you are after, you may simply use / as the first character of your url.

```
var getUsersUrl =  "/api/users";
```

---

**Here is an alternate approach** if you want more than just the app root (Ex : Specific urls( built using mvc helper methods such as `Url.RouteUrl` etc)

You should not hard code your app base path like that. You may use the `Url.Content` or `Url.RouteUrl` helper methods in your razor view to generate the url to the app base. It will take care of correctly building the url regardless of your current page/path.Once you get this value, assign it to a javascript variable and use that in your other js code to build your other urls. ***Always make sure to use javascript namespacing when doing so to avoid possible issues with global javascript variables.***

So in your razor view (Layout file or specific view), you may do this.

```
<script>
    var myApp = myApp || {};
    myApp.Urls = myApp.Urls || {};
    myApp.Urls.baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';    
    myApp.Urls.userListUrl = '@Url.Action("Index","User")';       
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/NonAngularJavaScript.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/AngularControllerForPage.js"></script>
<script>
    var a = angular.module("app").value("appSettings", myApp);
</script>
```

In your angular controller, you can access it like,

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
var ctrl = function (appSettings) {

    var vm = this;
    console.log(appSettings.Urls.userListUrl);

    vm.baseUrl = appSettings.Urls.baseUrl;
    //build other urls using the base url now
    var getUsersUrl = vm.baseUrl + "api/users";
    console.log(getUsersUrl);

};
app.controller("ctrl", ctrl)
```

You can also access this in your data services, directives etc.

In your non angular java script files.

```
// With the base url, you may safely add the remaining url route.
var urlToJobIndex2= myApp.Urls.baseUrl+"jobs/GetIndex";
```

Comment: This sounds like a really good approach. I'm only confused by this: var app = angular.module("app", []); and var a = angular.module("app").value("appSettings", myApp); . Why declare 'app' twice? (new to angular as well)

Comment: first one is creating the angular module and the second one(without the empty array as second param) is reading it back.

Comment: This looks like a very good solution - thank you. I'll keep pestering you with questions when they come along :)

Comment: I couldn't make it work properly (I know, I suck at figuring out app instantiation/call priority). So I just initiated a global javascript variable prior to registering my script files, and I referred to it from within the relevant files. Still, your idea guided me there so thank you :)

Comment: global variables are not a good idea. try to use js namespacing as i mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Using "~/" wouldn't work on plain HTML/JS files as far as I'm aware,
>   and this I can't really use it...

Yes, but you could inject it in your main server-side served webpage as a variable:

```
<script>
    var baseUrl = ... get the base url from the server using ~/
</script>
```

and then in your external scripts simply concatenate the relative urls with it. As far as static html files are concerned, then it could be a little more problematic. You could serve them through some special server side handler that will take care of injecting this logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `module.constant` to create an injectable which you can use.

```
app.constant("URL_BASE", "/Test");

app.directive('rpdbSpinner', function(URL_BASE) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        **templateUrl: URL_BASE + '/templates/directives/spinner.html',**
        scope: {
            isLoading:'='
        }
    }
})
```

You can also use `module.value` if you register it before you register your directive.

For more information see [AngularJS Module Guide -- configuration](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#configuration-blocks).