# changing textbox value on change of a dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I just wanted to change the value of the textbox when dropdownlist is changed can you tell me what's wrong? I'm really new in Jquery

code in my controller is just a sample I will do more after my code work

**View**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ddltype").change(function () {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("getWeightedAverage", "Employee")", { id: id }, function (Ave) {
                    $("#Average").val(Ave);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Grade</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.g_type, new List<SelectListItem>{
        new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Written Work"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "Performance Task"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Quarterly Assesment"},
        }, new {id = "ddltype" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.g_type)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.weighted_percent)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.weighted_percent, new { id = "Average" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.weighted_percent)
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
    public JsonResult getWeightedAverage(string id)
    {
        string Ave = "40";
        return Json(Ave, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Why `this.Average`?, just `$("#Average").val(Average);` would work.

Comment: still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the variable which has the response coming back from your server call. You do not need `this` keyword there.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddltype").change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON("../Employee/getWeightedAverage", { id: id }, function (res) {
            $("#Average").val(res);
        });
    });
});
```

I also recommend you to use `Url.Action` method to build the url instead of hard coding.

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("getWeightedAverage","Employee")", { id: id }, function (response) {
   $("#Average").val(response);
});
```

If your code is not in a razor view, but in an external js files, you build the base url in your razor view and use that in your js file as described in [this  answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419732/referencing-resources-in-a-global-way-either-from-a-virtual-directory-or-the-web/34420033#34420033)

Comment: It should work fine. Just verified it. I guess you have some other script error in the page.check your browser console.

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined     addGrade:7:9
which part is the error that's the only script i have

Comment: Are you loading jQuery before your custom script ?

Comment: Now Working Thank you so much for your help! i forgot that sorry newbie Here :)